# Do scripts in /etc/cron.hourly and /etc/cron.daily, etc., get executed automatically?

Tags: centos, cron

I've understood that the entries in `/etc/cron.d/` are executed automatically. But I have also found these in `/etc/`

```
/etc/cron.daily/
/etc/cron.hourly/
/etc/cron.monthly/
/etc/cron.weekly/
```

In `/etc/cron.d/` I found `0hourly` which has this content:

```
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

There are no files called `*daily`, `*monthly` or `*weekly`.

Does this mean that if I add a script in `/etc/cron.hourly` it will get executed automatically? And that this will NOT happen for scripts in `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.monthly/` and `/etc/cron.weekly/`?

EDIT:

My `/etc/crontab` is empty, except for initializing the variables `SHELL`, `PATH` and `MAILTO`.

In `/etc/cron.hourly/` I found the script `0anacron` which seems to check if `cron.daily` have been run today or not. I also found `/etc/anacron` which contains this:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1   5   cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7   25  cron.weekly     nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45 cron.monthly        nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

I guess it gave me some reading to do. Especially `anacron(8)` and `anacrontab(5)`.

Comment: What does your `/etc/crontab` contain?

Comment: @muru It initializes the variables SHELL, PATH and MAILTO but nothing more.

Comment: the only way to know for sure is to put a job in there and see if it actually runs or not ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It seems CentOS is like Ubuntu in this aspect, just configured slightly differently. Ubuntu uses anacron to run the daily/weekly/monthly jobs, and they're configured in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/anacrontab`.

With CentOS, first we have:

```bsh
# cat /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron
#!/bin/sh
# Check whether 0anacron was run today already
if test -r /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily; then
    day=`cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily`
fi
if [ `date +%Y%m%d` = "$day" ]; then
    exit 0;
fi

# Do not run jobs when on battery power
if test -x /usr/bin/on_ac_power; then
    /usr/bin/on_ac_power >/dev/null 2>&1
    if test $? -eq 1; then
    exit 0
    fi
fi
/usr/sbin/anacron -s
```

which checks/runs anacron once a day, and then:

```
# cat /etc/anacrontab
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1   5   cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7   25  cron.weekly     nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45 cron.monthly        nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

where the daily, weekly and monthly crontabs are configured.